# Is it possible to extract emails from a csv using a dos/cmd batch file?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, batch-processing, dos

I have a csv file with 1M email addresses and i need to extract them from the CSV to a text file.

I googled this and found very few links, and those that i found, didn't do the trick.

So is it even possible to extract emails from a csv using a dos/cmd batch file?
I now and it is possible to do it with Linux but saddly i'm have to use windows.

Comment: A comma-separated values (CSV) file stores tabular data (numbers and text) in plain text. _Plain text_ already...

Comment: Are there many columns in the csv file ? Please give one example with a fake email address. Why does it have to be a batch ? Do you need to do this often ?

Comment: You say you have to use windows - what about using powershell?

Comment: well i need it simple so my mom could use it... so i don't know if she could handle PS.

Comment: there are about 10 columns, the emails are located in diffrent columns

Answer (score 1):

```
Set Arg = WScript.Arguments
set WshShell = createObject("Wscript.Shell")
Set Inp = WScript.Stdin
Set Outp = Wscript.Stdout
'Remove ^ from quoting command line. Quote, ampersand and brackets
Pttn = Replace(Arg(2), "^(", "(")
Pttn = Replace(Pttn, "^)", ")")
Pttn = Replace(Pttn, "^&", "&")
Pttn = Replace(Pttn, "^""", """")
Set regEx1 = New RegExp
If Instr(LCase(Arg(1)), "i") > 0 then
    regEx1.IgnoreCase = True
Else
    regEx1.IgnoreCase = False
End If 
regEx1.Global = False
regEx1.Pattern = Pttn 
Do Until Inp.AtEndOfStream
    Line=Inp.readline
    Line = RegEx1.Replace(Line, Arg(3)) 
    outp.writeline Line
Loop
```

To use

```
cscript //nologo "c:\path to\scriptname.vbs" < inputfile.txt > outputfile.txt
```

**Replace**

```
filter replace {i|n} expression replace
filter repl {i|n} expression replace
```

Finds and replaces text using regular expressions.

Also used to extract substrings from a file.

Ampersands and brackets in expression must be escaped with the caret. Do not escape carets. Use hexidecimal code \x22 for quotes.

*SearchOptions*

*i - ignore case
n - none*

*Expression*

Regular Expression Reference

*Replace*

The text to replace. Use $1, $2, $..., $n to specify sub matches in the replace string

**Example**

```
filter replace i "=" "No equal sign" < "%systemroot%\win.ini"
```

This searches for text within square brackets and replaces the line with cat followed by the text within brackets

```
Filter replace i "^\[^(.*^)\]" "cat$1" < %windir%\win.ini
```

This searches for any text and prints from the 11th character to the end of the line.

```
Filter replace i "^.{10}^(.*^)$" "$1" < %windir%\win.ini
```

This searches a CSV file and prints the second and fourth field

```
Filter replace i "^.+,^(.+^),.+,^(.+^)$" "$1,$2" < csv.txt
```

Try a RegEx like (there are thousands on the internet like http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html)

```
[0-9a-zA-Z]+\.?[0-9a-zA-Z]?@[0-9a-zA-Z]+\.com|org|net|gov
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@set @code=@Batch   /*

@echo off
cscript //nologo //E:JScript "%~F0"
goto :EOF

@set @code=@JScript */

var fileContents = WScript.StdIn.ReadAll(),
    search = /(\w+)@(\w+)\.(\w+)/g, match;
while ( match = search.exec(fileContents) ) {
   WScript.Stdout.WriteLine(match[0]);
}
```

Copy previous code in a Batch file; for example: **GetEmails.bat**, and execute it redirecting the input/output files. This is the output of an example session:

```
C:\> type theFile.txt
Line, with, an, email, address, joedoe@unknown.org
Please, send, mail, to, george@contoso.com, and, someone@example.com, Thanks!
Line, number, 3, with, no, email, address

C:\> GetEmails.bat < theFile.txt
joedoe@unknown.org
george@contoso.com
someone@example.com
```